# How to plot univariate distribution using seaborn (pairplot diagonal only)?

Tags: python, pandas, seaborn

Which is the more pythonic way to plot the univariate distribution of a dataframe using seaborn only ?

```py
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = pd.DataFrame(
     np.random.normal(0,1,size=(15,3)),
     columns = ["A","B","C"]
)

sns.pairplot(data) # shows univariate distribution in the diagonal but add other plots 
plt.show()
```

Result :

[image: Result of the code]

I want to avoid plotting the other plots that are not in the diagonal. I can do so using matplotlib and subplots but I do think that there is a more pythonic and beautiful way, based on seaborn, to achieve this. I read the documentation and find `sns.FacetGrid` which may help (?) but I have no idea how to use it. I don't understand its parameter `col`...

Can someone help me ? Many thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pivot your data long first, so that you can split your columns in facets:

```
data.melt()

    variable    value
0   A   -0.510632
1   A   0.634505
2   A   1.158468
3   A   1.095242
4   A   -0.105571
5   A   1.385932
6   A   1.305856
7   A   -1.100260
8   A   -0.829865
9   A   1.094065
10  A   -0.380359
11  A   -1.394960
12  A   0.263192
13  A   -0.889774
14  A   0.427633
15  B   -0.983942
16  B   -0.109396
17  B   -0.392132
18  B   0.869097
19  B   0.921728
20  B   0.837788
21  B   -0.279346
[...]
```

You pass this into `FacetGrid` and call `histplot` :

```
g = sns.FacetGrid(data.melt(), col="variable")
g.map(sns.histplot, "value")
```

[image]

With the latest version of seaborn, you can call [displot](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.displot.html#seaborn.displot), as commented by @mwaskom:

```
sns.displot(data.melt(),col="variable",x="value",aspect=0.6)
```

[image]

Comment: Beautiful. Thank you so much.

Comment: Prefer `sns.displot` over `sns.FacetGrid` + `sns.histplot`.

Comment: Is there a way to make the `displot` version use multiple rows when there are many variables?